# Add image next to back button tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

What is the way to manage this tab bar distribution, I want to add a image next to back button and in the center of the content add a text

My code:

```
// Create the label
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Haz tu pedido"
label.sizeToFit()
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
label.medium(size: 20, fontFamily: .roboto, color: .white)
label.frame.origin.y = 0

// Create the image view
let image = UIImageView()
image.image = UIImage(named: "IconSmall.png")
let imageAspect = image.image!.size.width/image.image!.size.height
image.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x-label.frame.size.height*imageAspect , y: label.frame.origin.y, width: label.frame.size.height*imageAspect, height: label.frame.size.height)

image.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit

let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [image,label])
stack.axis = .horizontal

self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView = stack
```

Comment: Have you tried add image in ``leftBarButtonItem``?

Comment: Please make a Mock app when this problem could be reproducible and seem, with just the viewDidLoad part I can't help you much, just make guesses.

Answer (score 1):

use.  **leftBarButtonItem**. &. **title**

```
 self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Haz tu pedido"
 self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named: "IconSmall.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Back button image and style using UIkit and add a leading icon so it looks like what you need, do note that modifiyng the `navigation bar` will modify it in all the App.

```
import SwiftUI

        struct backbutton: View {
         
            init() {
                let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

                appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
                appearance.shadowColor = .clear
                appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
                appearance.backgroundEffect = nil

                //Button
                let buttonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(
                    style: .plain
                )

                buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
                    .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0)//
                ]

                let backimage = UIImage(
                    systemName: "pencil"
                )?.withTintColor(
                    UIColor.red,
                    renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal
                )
                appearance.backButtonAppearance = buttonAppearance
                appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(
                    backimage,
                    transitionMaskImage: backimage
                )

                UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
                UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
                UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            }
            
            var body: some View {
                
                NavigationStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: secondView()) {
                        Text("Navigate")
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("This is my first view")
                }
            }
        }

        struct secondView: View {
            
            @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
            
            var body: some View {
                Text("Second view")
                    .navigationTitle("This is my second view")
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: BackButton(presentationMode: _presentationMode, foregroundColor: .red))
            }
            
        }

        struct BackButton: View {
            
            @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
            var foregroundColor: Color
            
            var body: some View {
                Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                    HStack {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: FYI - the OP is using UIKit, not SwiftUI.